# How to apply rotation to an ellipse defined by center and axis lengths?

Tags: matlab, rotation, rotational-matrices

This is embarassing, but however. My ellipse is defined by:

- `centerX` and `centerY`;
- `majorAxis` and `minorAxis`, lengths of both axis;
- `orientation`, angle between the horizontal X axis and the major axis of the ellipse.

I started plotting the ellipse with its major axis parallel to the X axis:

```
theta = 0 : 0.05 : 2*pi;
orientation=orientation*pi/180;
xx = (majorAxis/2) * sin(theta) + centerX;
yy = (minorAxis/2) * cos(theta) + centerY;
%plot(xx,yy)
```

Now I only have to rotate this stuff by `orientation` degrees or radiants. Any help? I tried a lot of stuff, e.g.:

- plotting and then `rotate`ing the object;
- defining a rotation matrix `R = [cos(orientation), -sin(orientation); sin(orientation), cos(orientation)];` and applying it to `xx-centerX` and `yy-centerY`.

For some reason I can't get desired results. Of course I need points to be rotated around the center, not the origin.

**Side note**: if this is any help, I'm trying to plot ellipses defined by [`regionprops`](http://it.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html#inputarg_properties), using the `Centroid`,`MajorAxisLength`,`MinorAxisLength` and `Orientation` properties.

---

To @Luis Mendo, here's what I get:

[image]

and this is another try:

[image]

For the bottom feature I'm getting `orientation = 8` degrees, more or less, which is totally reasonable. But using your code, which I'm posting below, I get a `-8` ellipse!

```
       theta = 0 : 0.05 : 2*pi;
       orientation=orientation*pi/180;
       delta_x = (majorAxis/2) * sin(theta);
       delta_y = (minorAxis/2) * cos(theta);
       delta_x_ok = delta_x*cos(orientation) - delta_y*sin(orientation);
       delta_y_ok = delta_x*sin(orientation) + delta_y*cos(orientation);
       plot(delta_x_ok + centerX, delta_y_ok + centerY, 'r', 'LineWidth', 1.3);
```

Comment: Issue with the y-axis was tricky, but can't believe this got upvoted ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xx-centerX` and `yy-centerY` can be interpreted as coordinates with respect to axes *aligned* and *centered* with the rotated ellipse. To obtain coordinates with respect to the actual (non-rotated, non-centered) axes, say `xx2` and `yy2`, you only need to apply the transformation

```
xx2 = (xx-centerX)*cos(orientation) - (yy-centerY)*sin(orientation) + centerX;
yy2 = (xx-centerX)*sin(orientation) + (yy-centerY)*cos(orientation) + centerY;
```

Then plot the rotated ellipse with

```
plot(xx2,yy2)
```

Example:

```
majorAxis = 2;
minorAxis = 1;
centerX = 10;
centerY = 15;
orientation = -45;

theta = 0 : 0.05 : 2*pi;
orientation=orientation*pi/180;
xx = (majorAxis/2) * sin(theta) + centerX;
yy = (minorAxis/2) * cos(theta) + centerY;

xx2 = (xx-centerX)*cos(orientation) - (yy-centerY)*sin(orientation) + centerX;
yy2 = (xx-centerX)*sin(orientation) + (yy-centerY)*cos(orientation) + centerY;
plot(xx2,yy2)
axis equal
grid
```

[image]

The gap in the ellipse is produced because the `theta` step does not divide `2*pi`. To correct that, use for example

```
theta = linspace(0, 2*pi, 150);
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: I tried this before, but look what I get (edited question for you).

Comment: So what's wrong with your result? Maybe the sign of `orientation`?

Comment: I mean, either this method is wrong (which does not look so), or the orientation value returned by regionprops is. Will try with -orientation now.

Comment: thank you, I made this work with `-orientation`, but could you tell me why? Your code should use CCW angles, and so does `regionprops` with the `Orientation` value. I'm posting a test image; in the bottom rectangle, I get `orientation = 8` degrees (nearly), which is reasonable; but why do I get a `-8` ellipse using your code?

Comment: OK, I got it. I'm plotting over an image with `hold on` , so probably in that case the Y axis goes from top to bottom in respect to the image convention. So your code works if I call `yy2=-yy2`.

Comment: @miav Good catch. The automatic choice of _y_-axis direction can be confusing sometimes. As you probably know, you can change it with `axis ij` (or `set(gca,'YDir','reverse')`) and `axis xy` (or `set(gca,'YDir','normal')`)

Answer (score 0):

The `orientation` can be an offset to the `theta` angle.

```
theta = 0 : 0.05 : 2*pi;
orientation=orientation*pi/180;
xx = (majorAxis/2) * sin(theta + orientation) + centerX;
yy = (minorAxis/2) * cos(theta + orientation) + centerY;
%plot(xx,yy)
```

**update** this will only change the starting point of the ellipse, which has no effect.

Comment: Maybe it can, but not this way. Changing both `sin` and `cos` with a constant value is like defining `theta=orientation:(2*pi+orientation)`. In the end this does nothing, as I'm tracing the same exact curve.

Comment: oh yes, this is wrong. it will simply change the starting point of rotation. the result in such a case will indeed be the same.